# SQLite is not fetching text from TextView

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-database

i am using sqlite and i have some textview in a xml file.The process is to fetch the text from textview and save those in database.But i am unable to fetch text from textview.why?
i.e. it fetches data from editText.

Comment: Please add the code so we could help you more effectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch data from **TEXT VIEW** use

```
String text=textViewName.getText().toString();
```

now you can use the text string and send it to your database

Comment: you have no idea how much thnx u deserve....i was stuck for 2 days with this problem.thnx a bunch!